# C# DateTimePicker drop down is not localized

Tags: c#, .net, datetimepicker

My Windows System Regional settings Format is based on English (United Status). In my application, I am setting the `Format` and `CustomFormat` properties of C# DateTimePicker based on my current regional settings(maintained in my application).

```
base.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;

base.CustomFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";
```

The selected Date/Time is displayed properly using the CustomFomat.

But the Today's date displayed on the Drop down calendar is not localized. It is still in English format (`mm/dd/yyyy`). The CustomFormat is not applied to this field. How do I change the Today's date to my custom format?

Comment: DTP is a native Windows control.  The English version of Windows will always display English text.  Never a real problem, your user from who-knows-where with his own localized version of Windows already knows what his version of DTP looks like.

Comment: As @HansPassant said, it's "normal behaviour", see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889834/the-datetimepicker-and-monthcalendar-control-do-not-reflect-the-curren